# A question about JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to do something like this to fill a parts table:

```
SELECT (CASE t1.part IS NULL THEN t2.part ELSE t1.part END) AS partno,
       t3.desc    
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN join t2 ON [certain condition]
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.part = t3.part 
             OR t2.part = t3.part
```

...so this will select the value for partno from t2 in case that part is null in t1, then i need to take the description from t3 but when I run it it takes forever and never return the results, How can I do this faster? if I am missing some details please ask.

this are the tables

[alt text http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/3878/74385879.png](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/3878/74385879.png)

this is the actual procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getMonthDetail` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `getMonthDetail`(fechai Date, wid int)
BEGIN

select distinct
ins.inventoryinid,
(
select group_concat(concat(documents.documentname,': ', inventoryin_documents.documentno))
from inventoryin_documents
left join documents on documents.documentid=inventoryin_documents.documentid
where inventoryin_documents.inventoryinid = docin.inventoryinid
group by inventoryin_documents.inventoryinid
)as docin,
trace.inventoryoutid,
(
select group_concat(concat(documents.documentname,': ', inventoryout_documents.documentno))
from inventoryout_documents
left join documents on documents.documentid=inventoryout_documents.documentid
where inventoryout_documents.inventoryoutid = docout.inventoryoutid
group by inventoryout_documents.inventoryoutid
) as docout,
outs.inventoryoutdate,
(case when trace.partnumberp is null then indetails.partnumberp else trace.partnumberp end) as nopart,
p.descriptionsmall,
trace.quantity


from
inventoryin as ins
left join inventoryinouttrace as trace on trace.inventoryinid = ins.inventoryinid
left join inventoryin_documents as docin on docin.inventoryinid = ins.inventoryinid
left join inventoryout_documents as docout on docout.inventoryoutid = trace.inventoryoutid
left join inventoryout as outs on outs.inventoryoutid = trace.inventoryoutid
left join inventoryindetails indetails on ins.inventoryinid = indetails.inventoryinid
left join product as p on trace.partnumberp=p.partnumberp

where
((ins.inventorydate > fechai+0 and ins.inventorydate < fechai+100)
or (outs.inventoryoutdate > fechai+0 and outs.inventoryoutdate < fechai+100));

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

and when I Hit the explain button in the query browser it returns a error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
   SELECT COALESCE(t1.part, t2.part) AS partno,
          COALESCE(t3.desc, t4.desc)    
     FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN join t2 ON [certain condition]
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.part = t1.part
LEFT JOIN t3 AS t4 ON t4.part = t1.part
```

OR's are notorious for poor performance.

Comment: LOL never thought of joining t3 a second time, that is fast enough, thanks

Comment: COALESCE is ANSI standard - that will work on SQL Server or Oracle as is, while IFNULL would have to be changed.

Comment: if OR's are slow, is there a way to do WHERE's like faster?

where condition1 or condition3 or......

Comment: @Luiscencio: Use the `IN` syntax when you have multiple OR possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

OR clauses run slow and you should consider replacing them with a UNION which would still utilize any INDEXES you may have on your t1, t2, and t3 tables:

```
SELECT IFNULL(t1.part, t2.part) AS partno, t3.desc
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (condition here)
LEFT JOIN t3 ON (t1.part = t3.part)

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT IFNULL(t1.part, t2.part) AS partno, t3.desc
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (condition here)
LEFT JOIN t3 ON (t2.part = t3.part)
```

Also, your CASE() function, much the same as my simplified IFNULL() function, ends up using a temporary table.  This is unavoidable when utilizing such functions.

Comment: Agreed: every time I use an OR in the ON ... part of a join, it takes forever to complete.

Comment: The DISTINCT keyword on the isn't necessary - if it's omitted, UNION DISTINCT is implied: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

Tell us the actual structure of the data and please **show us the EXPLAIN of the query so we can see why it runs slow!**

Only a guess: *Are there indexes on the right coumns?*

Answer (score 0):

Your certain condition should be `t2.id=t1.id` and have more where clauses in your WHERE statement.

You may want to simplify this down to just have two select statements and see if it is slow, first.

You may be missing an index that would be helpful.

Once the two selects are fine, then you can add in the `case` command to the sql, and see what is going on, but don't change anything else in your query.

Then, you can give queries and times, which will help people to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for the bleeding obvious : I suppose you have indexed the fields that you use in your joins?